# NSDictionary from table sections and content

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview, nsdictionary

**Edit: Updated code**

I'm trying to create a dictionary from table sections and then the index list within each section, so the section letter would be the key... For the sections I have:

```
self.collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];

NSInteger index, sectionTitlesCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];

NSMutableArray *newSectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:sectionTitlesCount];

NSString *alphabet = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];

for (index = 0; index < sectionTitlesCount; index++) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [newSectionsArray addObject:array];

    NSString *letter = [alphabet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)];
    [myDict setObject:newSectionsArray forKey:letter];

    [array release];
}
```

This crashes with:

```
'*** -[NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

Then for each letter I need to add the data for that section, I think this array would be the object for the section/letter key:

```
for (Data *myData in self.dataModel.datalist) {

    NSInteger sectionNumber = [collation sectionForObject:myData collationStringSelector:@selector(myName)];

    NSMutableArray *sectionData = [newSectionsArray objectAtIndex:sectionNumber];

    [sectionData addObject:myData];

}
```

Hope this makes sense! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your sections in an array

```
        sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"#", @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"o", @"p", @"q", @"r", @"s", @"t", @"u", @"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", @"z", nil];
```

implement the delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tView {
    return [sections count];
}


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sections;
}
```

Then in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` you can get your subsection of the data

```
NSArray *sectionArray = [myData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [sections objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]]];
```

Comment: This seems much simpler to be honest, damn Apple examples sent me off on the obscure collation route! That filtered array would work for the filtered search results? Many thanks!!!

Comment: The reason Apple demonstrate using `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` is because it aids localization. Using the above technique will always provide an English alphabet regardless of the device's current language.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. It was the only demo of an indexed tableview I could find by Apple.

Comment: Which is why they demo it that way, it's considered best practice.

Answer (score 0):

With regards the crash, it's suggesting that the value of **sectionTitlesCount** is greater than the number of characters in the string **alphabet**.

I'm not sure what value **sectionTitlesCount** represents or where it comes from (*as this is absent from your code*), but it'd be better to replace the first line of your *for loop* with

```
for (index = 0; index < alphabet.length; index++) {
```

Comment: Your still not showing what the **physical** value of sectionTitlesCount is? If you place `NSLog(@"%i", sectionTitleCount);` directly below where you set it, what value is printed to the log?

Comment: Ah, sorry... it returns "sectionTitlesCount 27" (27 times)

Comment: Right, which is why it's crashing because there are only 26 characters in the English alphabet. Have you not see the examples [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html) which demonstrate doing it without hard-coding an index array?

Comment: You need to inspect `[collation sectionTitles]` to see what it's returning, but my guess is it's also including a # to represent numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Post your sectionTitlesCount value. It might be greator than the length of string.